# Firestore - Some doubts about Transactions and locking

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working with the Cloud Functions on a couponing system that assign a coupon to user, when he verifies his mail address.

For my design, I've a /coupons collections with a lot of coupons preloaded.

The user verifies his mail address invoking an HTTP firebase function, into this I would like to assign the coupon to user picking one from coupons collections querying by a field named "userId" on coupons collection.

Sample of query:

```
const pickOne = () => {
    return firestore
        .collection('coupons')
        .where('userId', "==", 'none')
        .limit(1)
}
```

I know the Firestore Transactions.

My idea (if possibile) is to invoke pickOne as parameter of transaction get() function, and write value "userId" on it, then close and commit the transaction.

My doubt is related to locking system: is it possible to avoid that concurrent users could have same coupons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this type of query in a transaction to effectively find a single document for a user, write their ID in it, and prevent it from being used again in other transactions with the same query.  It only works with backend SDKs (like nodejs) and not client SDKs.  I've done exactly this sort of things in other projects.

See the [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/transaction#_google_cloud_firestore_Transaction_get_member_1_) for details.

The only thing you should be aware of is, under high write pressure, the transaction might fail due to being [retried](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#transactions_and_data_contention) too many times.  In that case, you would have to either show an error or manually retry in your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick answer. Since this is a coupon assigned after a mail verification, I think that there are very few possibilities to get a lot of concurrent writes. My concerns were due to having the same coupon for multiple users. I try, thanks!

Comment: As long as there are no other writes outside of transactions happening to the document you get, it should be OK.

Comment: Ok Doug, great!! Last question: since pickOne function is invoked within a transaction, and this transaction is opened within a trigger, if this trigger (.auth.user.onCreate) is executed concurrently I'm sure that the transaction retries if the document queried will be updated, is it right? For example: if I have two coupon (COU001 and COU002 with two documents) and two users who register at the same time, the same transaction should return COU001 to the both users, but only one fires the update, then the transaction retries and get the COU002. Is it correct?

Comment: This function will not work if simply invoked inside a transaction.  You need to use the object provided to the transaction callback to make the query.  Please see the API documentation I linked to and review the transaction documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions